# Doing ILDASM Tool using winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tutorial to implement "My Own ILDASM" , may I know what approach i can use.

I have visual studio 2010 installed on my computer , i added `MenuStrip` and `OpenFIleDialog`.

My Questoins

1) I need to add a `treeview` control to display type members hierarchy in a tree

any direction will be enough

after selecting a dll from winform , how can i show that dll info in the tree view.

Any info will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, bone up on [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Then, build up the namespaces and have those as top level tree view items. Next get all the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx)s. For example: [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx).

From here you should be getting the hang of it. For each type, get the methods, properies, fields etc and make the subnodes.

Comment: you mean to say , load the dll and use reflection to get all the info and then bind to the tree?

Comment: Yep. You'll probably have to build the sub items manually though, rather than using databinding